# developing a add to index method in generic linked list class

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, linked-list

I'm having some trouble implementing an add method into a generic linked list class which adds a value at a given index. However, I can't be doing it correctly when running it through a test class I'm getting the following errors:

```
1) t31AddtoEmptyList(LinkedListTest$Add2Test)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

2) t32AddtoThreeItemList0(LinkedListTest$Add2Test)
java.lang.AssertionError: four element list has wrong size. expected:<4> but was:<3>

3) t35AddtoThreeItemList3(LinkedListTest$Add2Test)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

This is my add at index method:

```
public void add(int index, E value){
    if (index < 0 || index >= this.size) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    //if empty add to front
    }else if(index == 0) {
        front = new ListNode(value, front);
    // if index is last element add to front
    }else if(index == size){
        add(value);
    }else {
        ListNode current = front;
        for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++){
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = new ListNode(value, current.next);
    }
    this.size++;

}
```

And my full class:

```
public class LinkedList<E>{

    int size;

    private class ListNode{
        E data;
        ListNode next;

        ListNode(E data) {
            this.data = data;
            next = null;
        }

        ListNode(E data, ListNode next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    private ListNode front;
    private ListNode end;

    // Constructor
    // Construct an empty LinkedList object.
    public LinkedList(){
        this.size = 0;
        this.front = null;
    }

    // Return the size (number of items) in this LinkedList.
    public int size(){
        return size;
    }

    // Return true if this LinkedList has no items.
    // Return false if the size is greater than zero.
    boolean isEmpty(){
        return size() == 0;
    }

    //  Add the given element, value, to the end of the list.
    // appends
    public void add(E value){
        if (front == null) {
            front = new ListNode(value);
        } else {
            ListNode current = front;
            while (current.next != null) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = new ListNode(value);
        }
        this.size++;
    }

    // Add the given element, value, to the list at the given index.
    // After this operation is complete, get(index) will return value.
    // This operation is only valid for 0 <= index <= size().
    public void add(int index, E value){
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        //if empty add to front
        }else if(index == 0) {
            front = new ListNode(value, front);
        // if index is last element add to front
        }else if(index == size){
            add(value);
        }else {
            ListNode current = front;
            for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++){
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = new ListNode(value, current.next);
        }
        this.size++;

    }

    /*
    // prepend helper method
    //prepend
    public void prepend(int data){
        if (front == null){
            end = new ListNode();
            front = end;
        }
        else {
            front = new ListNode(data,front);
        }
        size++;
    }
    */

    // Return the element of the list at the given index.
    // This operation is only valid for 0 <= index < size().
    // This operation does not modify the list.
    public E get(int index){

        // check for index out of bounds
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        // returns char at index
        ListNode curr = front;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return curr.data;
    }

} // end class
```

my test class https://gist.github.com/Silverfin13/e22d061c2daf0d3a7013

I appreciate any help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (index < 0 || index >= this.size) {
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
```

Here `index >= this.size` condition at the top of `public void add(int index, E value)`is the problem 
I guess it should be `index > this.size`

Why? If you want to add at a node in the last position `index` will be equal to the current `size` and it's valid.

You also have `else if(index == size)` this condition so it's mean you want to allow `index` equal to the `size` but at the top you throwing a `new IndexOutOfBoundsException();` for that.

---

You have another problem in the size maintaining.

`public void add(int index, E value)` this method increase the size `this.size++;` for any valid insert. but for in case of `index==size`

```
else if(index == size){
        add(value);
```

you calling the `public void add(E value)` method which also increase the size at the end of operation for in case of `index==size` `this.size` increased twice.

Comment: right my else if(index == size) would never work with index >= this.size however I still run into the same errors, showing I likely have a more substantial problem.

Comment: you have fixed this and you still getting IndexOutOfBoundsException ?

Comment: my mistake, yes correcting this leaves me with just the assertion error: 1) t35AddtoThreeItemList3(LinkedListTest$Add2Test)
java.lang.AssertionError: four element list has wrong size. expected:<4> but was:<5>

Comment: this is the test class I am using https://gist.github.com/Silverfin13/e22d061c2daf0d3a7013

Comment: Ah wow, nice catch i've applied the size increment to just the other statements, thanks for your help!